# Strange call of copy constructor and destructor

Tags: c++

This question is different from all of:

- [Copy constructor calls destructor c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16177157/copy-constructor-calls-destructor-c) (unrelated)
- [c++ Copy constructors and destructors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51186060/c-copy-constructors-and-destructors) (unrelated)
- [extraneous calls to copy-constructor and destructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2657752/extraneous-calls-to-copy-constructor-and-destructor) (**related** but not STL used in my case)
- [Why is the destructor of the class called twice?] ([Why is the destructor of the class called twice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627540/why-is-the-destructor-of-the-class-called-twice)) (unrelated)
- [Constructor and destructor Calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16143522/constructor-and-destructor-calls) (unrelated)
- [copy constructor,destructor and temporaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32480806/copy-constructor-destructor-and-temporaries) (unrelated)

which are suggested by stack overflow.

---

Say you have this simple code.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Int {

    private:

        int i_;

    public:

        Int(Int &&obj) : i_(obj.i_) { //move constructor
            print_address_change_(&obj);
            cout << i_ << " moved.\n";
        }

        Int(const Int &obj) : i_(obj.i_) { //copy constructor
            print_address_change_(&obj);
            cout << i_ << " copied.\n";
        }

        Int(int i) : i_(i) {
            print_address_();
            cout << i_ << " constructed.\n";
        }

        ~Int() {
            print_address_();
            cout << i_ << " destructed.\n";
        }

        void print_address_() const {
            cout << "(" << this << ") ";
        }

        void print_address_change_(const Int *p) const {
            cout << "(" << p << " -> " << this << ") ";
        }

        const Int operator * (const Int &rhs) const {
            return Int(i_ * rhs.i_);
        }

};

int main() {

    Int i(3);
    Int j(8);

    cout << "---\n";
    Int k = i * j;
    cout << "---\n";

}
```

The result (by g++ 7.3.0 with default option) is this.

```
(0x7ffd8e8d11bc) 3 constructed. //i
(0x7ffd8e8d11c0) 8 constructed. //j
---
(0x7ffd8e8d11c4) 24 constructed. //tmp
---
(0x7ffd8e8d11c4) 24 destructed. //k
(0x7ffd8e8d11c0) 8 destructed. //j
(0x7ffd8e8d11bc) 3 destructed. //i
```

OK. A little strange but you can say [copy elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) must have occurred. So now with `-fno-elide-constructors` option, you get the following result.

```
(0x7ffd8f7693f8) 3 constructed. //i
(0x7ffd8f7693fc) 8 constructed. //j
---
(0x7ffd8f7693c4) 24 constructed. //tmp
(0x7ffd8f7693c4 -> 0x7ffd8f769404) 24 moved. //tmp -> ??? (WHY?)
(0x7ffd8f7693c4) 24 destructed. //tmp
(0x7ffd8f769404 -> 0x7ffd8f769400) 24 copied. //??? -> k (WHY?)
(0x7ffd8f769404) 24 destructed. //??? (WHY?)
---
(0x7ffd8f769400) 24 destructed. //k
(0x7ffd8f7693fc) 8 destructed. //j
(0x7ffd8f7693f8) 3 destructed. //i
```

This includes three more lines (which marked as "WHY") than I expected. What is `???`? Could anyone please tell me what happened there?

Comment: Move construction to move the returned value, and a copy-construction of `k`. Stepping through the code with the debugger should confirm this. Remember, copy elision has been turned-off.

Comment: Returning a `const Int` from `operator*` seems strange. It's the reason you get a copy and not a second move.

Comment: When you return something without copy elision, it has to be copied/moved to a temporary object. You create a temporary with `Int(i_ * rhs.i_)`, which is then moved into another temporary when you return it.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Thank you. I understand now.

Comment: @super Is that so? This implementation is (edited) excerpt from *Effective C++ 3rd Edition*. You can see the related page from [GoogleBooks](https://books.google.co.jp/books?id=Qx5oyB49poYC&printsec=frontcover&hl=ja#v=onepage&q=something%20essentially%20equivalent&f=false). I wonder if there is a better implementation.

Comment: @ynn You can return `Int` instead of `const Int`. I don't see any reason you would want to return a `const` variable in this case. Do you?

Comment: All you want to know about this, you will find by reading about RVO (Return Value Optimization).  Your `-fno-elide-constructors` option disabled RVO.

Comment: @super Yes. I deliberately return `const Int` instead of `Int`. If you return `Int`, expression like `if (a * b = c)` (this is typo of `if (a * b == c)`) is **well-formed**. This is not good in terms of class design, and returning `const Int` is so recommended in the book. (Also, returning `Int` doesn't change the result in this case as far as I tested now.)

Comment: @ ynn No. Second copy was changed to move, as @super said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write:

```
Int k = i * j;
```

You are actually doing something like:

```
Int tmp1(i.operator*(j));
Int k(tmp1);
```

That is, initialization with `=` is actually used by creating a temporary and doing a copy-construction. Compare with `Int k(i * j)` or `Int k{i *j}` that does direct initialization.

Not that it really matters in this case, because even if you write `Int k(i*j)` a temporary is still needed to hold the return value of `operator*` before calling the copy constructor of `k`.

The `operator*` is equivalent to:

```
Int tmp2(24);
return std::move(tmp2);
```

So your output means:

```
(0x7ffd8f7693f8) 3 constructed. //i
(0x7ffd8f7693fc) 8 constructed. //j
---
(0x7ffd8f7693c4) 24 constructed. //tmp2 inside operator*
(0x7ffd8f7693c4 -> 0x7ffd8f769404) 24 moved. //return value into tmp1
(0x7ffd8f7693c4) 24 destructed. //tmp2
(0x7ffd8f769404 -> 0x7ffd8f769400) 24 copied. //k = tmp1
(0x7ffd8f769404) 24 destructed. //tmp1
---
(0x7ffd8f769400) 24 destructed. //k
(0x7ffd8f7693fc) 8 destructed. //j
(0x7ffd8f7693f8) 3 destructed. //i
```

Comment: You have two destructors commented for `tmp2` and none for `tmp1`...

Comment: @BenVoigt: Obvious typo... thanks, fixed.

Answer (score 3):

`operator*` constructs a temporary object with `Int(i_ * rhs.i_)`. It returns that object, which constructs a second temporary object outside the function. That temporary object gets copied into `k`.